# I'm getting this error "RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout" but i'm working with " boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)"

Tags: android

whenever i'm commenting this code, the application works fine, but with this code i'm getting this error

E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: online.ds.primeaddict.eorder, PID: 13600
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f07006f

please help me, i'm new here please be kind, Thank You

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
final MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_cart);
View actionView = MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem);
TextView textCartItemCount = (TextView) 
actionView.findViewById(R.id.cart_badge);    
actionView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
}
});
return true;
}
```

> main_menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
android:id="@+id/action_cart"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp"
android:title="Cart"
app:actionLayout="@layout/custom_action_item_layout"
app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

> custom_action_item_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout      
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
style="?attr/actionButtonStyle"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:focusable="true">

<ImageView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:src="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/cart_badge"
android:layout_width="20dp"
android:layout_height="20dp"
android:layout_gravity="right|end|top"
android:layout_marginEnd="-5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="-5dp"
android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:padding="3dp"
android:text="0"
android:textColor="@android:color/white"
android:textSize="10sp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

UPDATE: here is my mainActivity

> mainActivity.java

```
package online.ds.primeaddict.eorder;


public class Home2Activity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

DrinkShopAPI mService;

CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
RecyclerView mainMenu;
SliderLayout mainSlider;
TextView badgeText;
TextView navName, navPhoto;
CircleImageView circleImage;
Uri uri;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home2);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    mService = Common.getAPI();
    mainSlider = findViewById(R.id.home_slider);
    mainMenu = findViewById(R.id.main_menu);
    mainMenu.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, 
LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
    mainMenu.setHasFixedSize(true);


    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", 
Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, 
R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    getMenu();
    getSliderImages();
    setUpHeadder(navigationView);
    initDatabase();
    getToppingList();

}


private void getMenu() {

    compositeDisposable.add(mService
            .getMenus()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Consumer<List<Category>>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(List<Category> categories) throws 
Exception {
                    Log.d("DEBUG", "getMenu()");
                    setUpMenu(categories);
                }
            }));
}

private void setUpMenu(List<Category> categories) {
    Log.d("DEBUG", "SetupMenu()");
    Log.d("DEBUG", String.valueOf(categories));
    CategoryAdapter categoryAdapterOne = new 
CategoryAdapter(Home2Activity.this, categories);
    Log.d("DEBUG", "adapter" + categoryAdapterOne);
    mainMenu.setAdapter(categoryAdapterOne);
}

private void getSliderImages() {

    compositeDisposable.add(mService
            .getBanners()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Consumer<List<Banner>>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(List<Banner> banners) throws Exception 
{
                    Log.d("DEBUG", "getSlider Images");

                    setUpSlider(banners);
                }
            }));
}

private void setUpSlider(List<Banner> banners) {
    HashMap<String, String> banner_map = new HashMap<>();
    for (Banner item : banners) {
        banner_map.put(item.getName(), item.getLink());
    }

    for (String name : banner_map.keySet()) {
        TextSliderView textSliderView = new 
TextSliderView(Home2Activity.this);
        textSliderView.description(name)
                .image(banner_map.get(name))
                .setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.Fit);

        mainSlider.addSlider(textSliderView);
    }

}

private void setUpHeadder(NavigationView navigationView) {
    View nav_headder = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    navName = nav_headder.findViewById(R.id.profile_name);

    navPhoto = nav_headder.findViewById(R.id.profile_phone);

    circleImage = nav_headder.findViewById(R.id.profile_avtar);
    //----------NAV NAME
    navName.setText(Common.currentUser.getName());
    //----------NAV PHONE
    navPhoto.setText(Common.currentUser.getPhone());
    //----------SETUP AVATAR----------//
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Common.currentUser.getAvtarUrl())) {
        Picasso.with(this)
                .load(String.valueOf(new StringBuilder(Common.BASE_URL)
                        .append("avtar_folder/")
                        .append(Common.currentUser.getAvtarUrl())))
                .into(circleImage);
    }
    //----------NAV PHOTO UPDATER
    circleImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //todo choosePhoto()
//                choosePhoto();
        }
    });
}

private void initDatabase() {
    Common.cartDatabase = CartDatabase.getInstance(this);
    Common.cartRepository = 
      }

private void getToppingList() {
    compositeDisposable.add(mService
            .getDrinksByMenuID(Common.TOPPING_ID)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Consumer<List<Drink>>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(List<Drink> toppings) throws Exception             
{
                    Common.toppingList = toppings;
                }
            }));
}



@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
//        updateCartCounter();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    compositeDisposable.dispose();
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home2, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
//        if (id == R.id.action_cart) {
//            Toast.makeText(this, "Cart activity",         
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//        }

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: pl add  recyclerview related code.

Comment: i think you miss setadapter into recyclerview

Comment: Your main problem is `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException:` . Look for line number in error .

Comment: provide full code snap , so contributes can give you perfect answer.

Comment: show full stacktrace

Comment: the problem is solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f07006f

This error means that your app trying to bind view with some id that doesn't exist. Check your ids. If everything is correct - invalidate cache and restart Android studio.

> E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

This warning in most cases means that list size with data in adapter is 0.

Try to call findViewById from menuItem and not from actionView

Comment: I've attached the mainActivity please can you tell me where is the problem?

Comment: this worked, the problem was with the "cart icon" thank you